# Optimizing Linq to MySql

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, profiler

Recently I use Entity Framework Profiler to monitor my sql that generating from
entity framework; I find some sql is not what I want;

here is packeages detail:

```
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MySql.Data" version="6.9.11" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MySql.Data.Entity" version="6.9.7" targetFramework="net452" />
```

there is c# code 1

```
    public void TestCount()
    {
        using (Model1 context = new Model1())
        {
            int count=context.GameUsers.Count();
        }
    }
```

what I am expected sql is like this：（some one of them）

```
select count(1) from User;

select count(*) from User;

select count(userId) from User;
```

Howerve ,the actual sql is this:

```
   SELECT `GroupBy1`.`A1` AS `C1`
   FROM   (SELECT COUNT(1) AS `A1`
   FROM   `USER_T` AS `Extent1`) AS `GroupBy1`
```

why there is a subquery? how can I optimize?

here is code 2;

```
  public void TestString()
        {
            string paramsFromInput = "12000"; 

            using (Model1 context = new Model1())
            {
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paramsFromInput))
                {
                    int count=context.GameUsers.Where(x => x.channel == paramsFomrInput).Count();
                }  
            }
        }
```

what I am expected sql is like this:

```
select count(1) from User where channel='1200'
```

howerver the actual sql is this:

```
SELECT `GroupBy1`.`A1` AS `C1`
FROM   (SELECT COUNT(1) AS `A1`
        FROM   `USER_T` AS `Extent1`
        WHERE  (`Extent1`.`channel` = '12000' /* @p__linq__0 */)
                OR ((`Extent1`.`channel` IS NULL)
                    AND ('12000' /* @p__linq__0 */ IS NULL))) AS `GroupBy1`
```

I don't want where condition : or channel` IS NULL (because It can't be null,I judge it in c# code), at the same time ,I don't want to subquery;

is there any problem with my code or understanding?
is there any problem with EF or mysql?
is there any problem with Entity Framework Profiler?

help~~~~~

supplement:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM USER_T;

SELECT COUNT(c) FROM (

SELECT COUNT(1) as c FROM USER_T

) as t
```

the test data is few;

there is sql profile result:even there is a few time difference (test data is few,but the show the different sql executing plan)

there is pics

[image]

[image]

so for better performance,we had better remove subQuery; however,linq generate the subquery;

Comment: Despite the unintuitive sql produced, its usually quite performant. Have you benchmarked against your own sql with sql profiler?

Comment: I'd take a look at the query plans. The plans for `select count(*) from User` and the more complex looking generated statement might very well be identical.

Comment: I do the sql profile,add some supplement;you can see question again;

Comment: the subquery use the temp table.....

Comment: So whats up with the `(master see here ! ! !)` in title are we doing YouTube scheme title now, whats next `OMG you dont believe what happened to me` ?

Comment: oh, I am so sorry for that , because no one answer this question,at  the same time, I am confused~